# Declaratively created content type is losing event receivers on list

Tags: content-type, elements-xml

I declaratively created a content type which has an attached event receiver. I attached this ct to a list which is also being done via xml declaration.
In principle all components are working. The event receiver is working, the list is being correctly created and the content type is being attached. But the event receivers are not being attached to the list.
To make the event receivers work I need to remove and re-attach the content type to the list. Once this has been done everything works as expected.

Some information to the feature which is being used.
One feature contains all required fields, the list instance and definition. I also tried to modify the sequence the components but with no result.
Does anyone has an idea why it is behaving like this?

Comment: what id does your content type have?

Comment: It is a folder based one: it starts with `0x012000E461C...`.

Comment: so you generated a new id?

Comment: It is a Visual Studio Solution in which I created a bunch of new columns, a folder inherited content type and a custom list. And I put all this together into a new feature.

Comment: I understand that, but if you use id's which are already present in sharepoint, your behaviour can occur, that's one possible mistake

Comment: Ahh now I see what you mean.  
These are newly generated IDs which are not present in the system at the time of deployment. Therefore I am a bit confused about this behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29924/discussion-between-husen-and-gwny).